# Flask environment variables being ignored (FLASK_ENV and FLASK_APP) WINDOWS 10

Tags: flask, cmd

After setting the environment variables FLASK_ENV and FLASK_APP running flask run will give me this error:
[image]

The snippet shows the command promt.
It says that environment is production and that I didn't provide the FLASK_APP environment variable, even though I typed them in. **Did I miss something or can someone explain why this error occurs?**

Comment: Your issue is very simply a result of bad syntax. Change from `set FLASK_ENV = development`, and `set FLASK_APP = src/app.py`, to `Set "FLASK_ENV=development"`, and `Set "FLASK_APP=src/app.py"`, respectively. The main problem is that unlike in many other languages, spaces either side of the `=` are included as part of both the variable name and the value, This means that you've created, for instance, a variable `FLASK_APP<SPACE>`, with a value of `<SPACE>src/app.py`. _The doublequotes are not included in either the variable name, or value, but provide hidden or poison character protection_.

Comment: David Lo, instead of simply accepting an answer which only part uses the correct syntax, the least you could have done was upvote, or better, respond to, my above comment, thanking me for providing the correct syntax, complete with expalnatory text. A responsible questioner, would possibly direct the author of the accepted answer, to view my comment, and adjust their answer to match, or improve upon, it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Linux you cannot have spaces around the equal sign. Maybe on Windows this is the same.

In the official Flask documentation you can read:

`set FLASK_APP=hello`

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/

Comment: This suggestion fixed my issue. Thanks. @Compo left a more explanatory answer in the comment which would be good to read into following your answer.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you this good read https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application on how to run Flask Application (there are 2 approaches)

i also recommend you reading this topic https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/?highlight=flaskenv#environment-variables-from-dotenv

the better approach is to create `.flaskenv` file in the root of your project where you set your environment variables like so :

in `/.flaskenv` file

```
FLASK_APP=myflaskproject:create_app()
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=0

# FLASK_RUN_EXTRA_FILES=
# FLASK_RUN_HOST=
# FLASK_RUN_PORT=8080
# FLASK_RUN_CERT=
# FLASK_RUN_KEY=
```

in `FLASK_APP` you call your app but usually it's recommended to use "Application Factory" pattern, see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

then

```
(.venv) flask run
```

don't forget to install `python-dotenv`

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
set flask<space>=<space>src/app.py
```

As you can see you are NOT setting `flask` but `flask<space>`. Flask may accept that path but it is an illegal windows path.