# Is there a way to run flask in debug mode using the `flask run` command without setting environment variables?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run a flask application in debug mode (or at least a mode where it will reload after changing the files).

I'm aware of `export FLASK_ENV=development`, however I am working on a university online development environment, and I lose the environment variables every time the site reloads, which while not the end of the world, is slightly annoying, and I'd rather avoid having to keep typing it (lazy I know).

If I include the following, and run using `python3 main.py`, debug mode is activated, however when using `flask run`, debug remains off.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

However, as I understand it, using the flask `run` command is the preferred way to launch the app, not using `python app.py`.

I've found ideas such as including the following, however none of these have activated debug mode, so I'm wondering whether it is even possible:

```
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True
```

I've simplified my code to the following to see if it was an error in my original piece, but it doesn't seem to be:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return '<h1>debugging!</h1>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Just do: FLASK_ENV=development flask run

Comment: have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623193/12368419

Comment: That's excellent. I did have a look through stack exchange but couldn't find much of use. Using that `.flaskenv` file works a dream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there does not seem to be a way of using `flask run` how I want without assigning environment variables, however using a `.flaskenv` file will allow environment variables to be loaded at run time.

The `.flaskenv` file for example could include the following ENVs among others to be loaded:

```
FLASK_APP=main:app
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Note - this does require `python-dotenv` to be installed to use.

All credit to @cizario who answered here with some more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623193/12368419

Answer (score 2):

Well, when it's Flask 2.2 or later, you can just do

```bash
flask --debug run
```

```
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 560-342-853
```